# Jquery horizontal slide div container

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I want to slide horizontally a div container with jquery.
I tried some js code but without success. How can I do it?
Is it possible to slide the div container(ajaxify-container) outside the main container (for example an outer-container with min-width= 768px)? 
To slide it inside the full width of page browser, if the main container do not the full width.

Here my code with a fade effect :

```
$("#ajaxify_container").fadeOut(1500, function () {
                $(this).html(data).fadeIn(1500, function () {
                    $('#LoadingImage').hide();
                });
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: I see fading and hiding, but I don't see any code for sliding. Can you post a complete code example and a jsFiddle if possible?

Comment: Depending on your HTML, you may need to use CSS like `position:absolute` and `overflow` on the parent to make `#ajaxify_container` be visible the way you want it to.

Comment: Here my website (this adress load the ajax container with the fade effect): http://freakyshape.com/#/portfolio/dock.html. I don't put a sliding effect because I don't know how to do. with this it don't work : $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});